# Objects are being spawned out of the screen in Unity

Tags: c#, android, random, unityscript

I'm learning on my first 2D game built in `Unity` on a tutorial and I hit a problem that I don't know how to solve. In this game there are randomly spawning clouds that must stay in the screen and this is written in `CloudSpawner` script:

I set `MaxX` and `MinX` according to the camera size:

```
  void setMinAndMaxX(){

        Vector3 bounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0));

        minX = -bounds.x + 0.5f;
        maxX = bounds.x - 0.5f;

    }
```

And here is the function that sets position to each cloud from clouds array:

```
void CreateClouds(){

        Shuffle (clouds);

        float positionY = 0f;

        for (int i = 0; i < clouds.Length; i++) {

            Vector3 temp = clouds [i].transform.position;

            temp.y = positionY;

            //temp.x = Random.Range (minX, maxX);

            if (controlX == 0) {

                temp.x = Random.Range (0, maxX);
                controlX = 1;

            } else if (controlX == 1) {

                temp.x = Random.Range (0, minX);
                controlX = 2;

            } else if (controlX == 2) {

                temp.x = Random.Range (1.0f, maxX);
                controlX = 3;

            } else if (controlX == 3) {

                temp.x = Random.Range (-1.0f, minX);
                controlX = 0;

            }

            lastCloudPositionY = positionY;

            clouds [i].transform.position = temp;

            positionY -= distanceBetweenClouds;

        }


    }
```

Let me explain what is the real problem here - the scripts should work as it is, but in `Unity` if I press PAUSE first and then hit PLAY, the clouds spawn well in the screen. But if I press just PLAY, clouds are being spawned also out of the screen. I have a feeling there is a problem with `Unity` software and maybe not with the code and I found a thread where it says it should be opposite (so if you press pause first and then play it could come to problems with spawning clouds - and not when you press just play).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. I'm currently using Unity version 5.3.1f1 where there is a slight difference using `screen.width` in my `SetMinAndMax()` function. I added `bounds.x = Mathf.Floor(bounds.x / 2);` like this:

```
void setMinAndMaxX(){

    Vector3 bounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0));

    bounds.x = Mathf.Floor(bounds.x / 2);

    minX = -bounds.x + 0.5f;
    maxX = bounds.x - 0.5f;

}
```